# How can I create a class able to add elements in the GUI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

Some time ago I downloaded a class that should be implemented along with a UIView. When you implemented a class in UIView, automatically the tab attributes inspector create new options as:

1. Boolean fields
2. Text fields
3. Numeric fields
4. UIView load some draws (Static)

How can I create a class like this? Can be done with only Objective-c or I will need to use C?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you asking about this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, thanks a lot :D